# Refactoring static class into multiple implementations

Tags: c#

I am using a cache item as described by https://blog.falafel.com/working-system-runtime-caching-memorycache/

However I need to develop a number of implementations of this class which use different tables within the ConsentDataContext item.

This class is a static, so I either need to change it to a singleton and then inherit from an abstract with GetItem and AddOrGetExisting methods defined. Or create two separate classes and use reflection to return the correct instance.

What would be the best way of solving this problem?

Implementation 1

```
public static class Consent1Cache
{
    private static MemoryCache _cache = new MemoryCache("ConsentType1Cache");

    public static object GetItem(string key)
    {
        return AddOrGetExisting(key, () => InitItem(key));
    }

    private static T AddOrGetExisting<T>(string key, Func<T> valueFactory)
    {
        var newValue = new Lazy<T>(valueFactory);
        var oldValue = _cache.AddOrGetExisting(key, newValue, new CacheItemPolicy()) as Lazy<T>;
        try
        {
            return (oldValue ?? newValue).Value;
        }
        catch
        {
            // Handle cached lazy exception by evicting from cache.
            _cache.Remove(key);
            throw;
        }
    }

    public static string InitItem(string consentNumber)
    {
        using (DLL.ConsentDataContext db = new DLL.ConsentDataContext())
        {
            return db.vw_ConsentType1.Where(x => x.ConsentNumber == consentNumber).Select(c => c.ConsentNumber + " - " + c.Proposal).FirstOrDefault();
        };
    }
}
```

Implementation 2

```
public static class Consent2Cache
{
    private static MemoryCache _cache = new MemoryCache("ConsentType2Cache");

    public static object GetItem(string key)
    {
        return AddOrGetExisting(key, () => InitItem(key));
    }

    private static T AddOrGetExisting<T>(string key, Func<T> valueFactory)
    {
        var newValue = new Lazy<T>(valueFactory);
        var oldValue = _cache.AddOrGetExisting(key, newValue, new CacheItemPolicy()) as Lazy<T>;
        try
        {
            return (oldValue ?? newValue).Value;
        }
        catch
        {
            // Handle cached lazy exception by evicting from cache.
            _cache.Remove(key);
            throw;
        }
    }

    public static string InitItem(string consentNumber)
    {
        using (DLL.ConsentDataContext db = new DLL.ConsentDataContext())
        {
            return db.vw_ConsentType2.Where(x => x.ConsentNumber == consentNumber).Select(c => c.ConsentNumber + " - " + c.Proposal).FirstOrDefault();
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Well you should not do either. The modern way of doing this is using Dependency injection And making this a proper Interface. If DI seams scary its really not, but you can implement a service locator pattern, I usually find it easier for people to understand and faster to implement.

Comment: Note that service-locator is considered a bit of an anti-pattern and can bite you *really hard* if you cache the results...

Comment: @BradleyDotNET yes I said DI first no need to panic. But I have to defend SL here as I already mention it's much simpler to implement and from experience it's much easier for people to understand. If he is not developing a large app with multiple developers and many unit tests I honestly don't think there is anything bad with SL.

Comment: @FilipCordas Just wanted to put it out there; nothing against you (and I use SL on small projects myself). I just recently ran into an issue where order of registration mattered when using SignalR's SL because the constructors of the registered objects looked up other dependencies in the constructor and *cached the answer*; causing future registrations to not have an effect. Very fun bug to find.

Comment: @FilipCordas Thanks how would I use DI here, as in how could I inject the table used to query against within the InitItem? Also would changing this from a static keep it threadsafe? I know a little knowledge is a dangerous thing :)

Comment: @BradleyDotNET I know I was just kidding. But SL has gotten a bad reputation as of late and people start worrying about stuff they won't ever have to deal with in their own code base because they are not writing a new Visual Studio. As everything in programming it has its positive sides and negative but best people learn all and see what they like.